# how to fade my background but not the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to start my blog but also I wished to make my own website. I just learnt how to do that using Codecademy. My question is how to fade my background but not the text ? I found a lot of solutions but none of them worked for me. 
My website: http://beingatechnocrat.me/
HTML code:

```
<article>
  <div class="post" style="background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_FOSmVKg.jpeg)">
    <div class="product">
      <h3>The Monarch</h3>
      <p>The Monarch Bike is our original beach cruiser. It's perfect for strolling bike rides down beach promenades and small enough to stash just anywhere.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

CSS code:

```
.post {
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: You can definitely do all of this in CSS rather than JavaScript/JQuery https://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: Hey Prashant, did my answer solve the question or do you still need help? If it's solved, be sure to accept it as a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply the background to a pseudo element instead, and use `opacity` on the pseudo element

```css
.post {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.background {
  position: relative;
}

.background:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  background-image: url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_FOSmVKg.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="post background">
  <div class="product">
    <h3>The Monarch</h3>
    <p>The Monarch Bike is our original beach cruiser. It's perfect for strolling bike rides down beach promenades and small enough to stash just anywhere.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir, I think there is a problem. I need to change the background picture for each and every container. You can have a look at my website.

Comment: If I follow your code...it does my work but only for one post.

Comment: @Prashant use a unique class that you apply to the post you want to have the background image.

Comment: @Prashant it's your responsibility to include all of the relevant code for the problem in your post. Don't just link to your website. I shouldn't have to dig through the code and reproduce it for you, then give you that code back. Provide the code you need help with in your original post.

Comment: I apologize. I need help with creating a new class.

Comment: <div class="post" style="background-image: url(https://bensmann.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/New-Blue-Profile.jpg)">
      <div class="product">
        <h3>The Monarch</h3>
        <p>The Monarch Bike is our original beach cruiser. It's perfect for strolling bike rides down beach promenades and small enough to stash just anywhere.</p>
        <a href="/posts/p9chargingonwheels.html" class="btn">Read More</a>
      </div>
   </div>

Comment: @Prashant I updated my answer with the change you need to make to the post you want to have a background.

Comment: @Prashant are you trying to hire me for work? If so you can contact me on LinkedIn - it's in my profile on stack overflow.

Comment: No Sir..I am not planning to hire you. Last question: How can I change the code to set different backgrounds for different sections of my website. and still having the fade

Comment: @Prashant that is beyond the scope of your original question. Assuming the problem in your original post is solved, accept a solution, try to set the backgrounds yourself, and if you can't figure it out, make a new post.